# Gridview header check box selection is always false in asp.net(populated using jquery ajax)

Tags: jquery, asp.net

on button click i have populated my grid view using jquery ajax using below code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#btnShowData").click(function () {
         $('#gvData').empty();
         load_data(0, 30);
     });
});

function load_data(iPageIndex, iPageSize) {
     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "GridAjaxDotnetSpan.aspx/BindEmployees",
            data: JSON.stringify({ iPageIndex: iPageIndex, iPageSize: iPageSize }),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                $('#gvData').empty();
                $('#gvData').append("<tr><th><input type='checkbox' id='chkOrgheader' name='chkOrgheader' onclick='selectAll();' /></th><th>EmpId </th><th>EmpName </th><th>empsal </th><th>empaddr </th></tr>")
                for (var i = 0; i < result.d.length; i++) {

                    $("#gvData").append("<tr><td><input type='checkbox' id='chkOrgRow' name='chkOrgRow' /></td><td>" + result.d[i].EmpId + "</td><td>" + result.d[i].EmpName + "</td><td>" + result.d[i].empsal + "</td><td>" + result.d[i].empaddr + "</td></tr>");
                }

                hideorshownavigation();
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
}
```

and on selection of header check box i want to select all child checkboxes. i have used below code.

```
 function selectAll() {

        var bool = $("#gvDatainput[id*='chkOrgheader']:checkbox").is(':checked');

        //var isChecked = $(checked).attr('checked') ? true : false; //tired this on also by passing "this" to chkOrgheader onclick="selectAll(this)"

        if (bool) {
            $('input:checkbox[name$=chkOrgRow]').each(
                function () {
                    $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
                });
        }
        else {
            $('input:checkbox[name$=chkOrgRow]').each(
                function () {
                    $(this).removeAttr('checked');
                });
        }
 }//End of select all
```

The above selectAll function is getting fired when i select header checkbox "chkOrgheader" but am always getting checked as false.

Am going in a right direction? please suggest me how to achieve this requirement.

I need help for below points:
1. When i select header check box, all the child checkboxes should select

2. when i select particular child check box i want to find out empsal field value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Point 1 -** Your below code does not select any `checkbox` because of improper `selector`. You need to give space between your id `#gvData` and `input` and you don't need `*` with `id` + no need to filter with `:checkbox` as you are selecting checkbox with `id` which will be unique. So just modify your code as below:

```
var bool = $("#gvData input[id='chkOrgheader']").is(':checked');
```

You might face some issue with `.attr` so I would suggest to use `.prop` instead

**[DEMO WITH `.prop`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/645sja2w/)** `//Works fine`

```
$(this).prop('checked', true); //check the checkbox

$(this).attr('checked',false);//uncheck the checkbox
```

**[DEMO WITH `.attr`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/645sja2w/1/)** `//checks and unchecks for the first time and then unfunctional`

**Point 2**

Since you are adding `checkboxes` dynamically you can use below `jquery` eventlistener to perform an action to get value

```
$(document).on('change','td input[type="checkbox"]',function(){
   if($(this).prop('checked'))
       alert($(this).parent('td').siblings('td:nth-child(4)').text()); //You can either store it in variable as per your needs
                                            ^^^^^^^Retrieves values of Column 4 which is salary
});
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/645sja2w/2/)**

Comment: Anytime!! Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: Thanks guruprasad. Its working fine. i have paging concept in my grid for the above example only. My first requirement is  suppose In first page i have selected first two employees and moved second page there also i have checked multiple employees. Then again if i moved to first page first two employee checkboxes should be checked and again if i move to second page whatever i checked earlier should be checked.  My second requirement is what ever the employee ids i am selecting those cumulative empsalary should be shown in textbox and if i uncheck any employees then salary should be deducted

Comment: @user1463065 I suggest you to post it as a separate question abiding by the rules of SO!! because that will be totally a different question and answer for the same will be different!! Now if you edit this question and post then whatever answer I've given mismatches!! Hope you are getting me! Provide a good demo if possible with jsfiddle.